# Rails: Include Association Value in ActiveRecord results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two objects: User and Picture.

One user has multiple pictures. I only want to include the "primary picture" url for that user in my ActiveRecord query. Url is a property of Picture and primary_picture_id is a property of user.

The goal here is to take the results and transform them into json for search results.

So what I want to do is something like:

```
User.where("...").select(:id, :title, {|user| user.primary_picture.path}).to_json
```

...but obviously that's not valid.

Is there a way to include a property from an associated object into the query results?

Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
User.includes(:primary_picture).select(:id, :title, :path)
```

Comment: Thank you! When I add that I get: (Object doesn't support #inspect)

Comment: I mean, call on that `to_json` but try that line in console too to see if this is what you want, it should work